# Displaying time using functions

Tags: vb.net

Using  **Label1.Text = Date.Now**  I was able to add  **"10-07-2013 06:59:30"**

I don't want the seconds to be displayed. How can I that in vb.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.ToString()` and specify the format, e.g.

```
Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Date.ToString() which, in one overload, allows you to to specify the precise date format emitted:

```
Date.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")
```

or

simply trim the default output to 10 characters:

```
Date.Now.ToString().Substring(1,10)
```

Comment: I would like to display Hour and Minute but not the Second

Comment: Then trim the output to 15 characters, or use the Date format "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm"  (or whatever your preferred display format is).   Here's the MSDN reference on DateTime formats:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx